# Delphi: Why Socket.ReadString(10) sometimes don't get the right data

Tags: multithreading, delphi

**Server:**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  len : integer;
  rest_packet : string;
  packet_length : string;
begin

        try
          // length 10, it will be the rest packet length: 0000000545
          // So the bug is in ReadBytes(10) , some times it do not receive the length 0000000015 but receive a mix of data+length, something like: "00015Hello" or "loWorldApp" etc.
          packet_length := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadString(10);
        except
          on E:Exception do begin Exit; end;
        end;

        // Convert string to int: 0000000545 , to 545
        try
          len := StrToInt(packet_length);
        except
          on E:Exception do begin Exit; end;
        end;


        // get reset of data, size: 545
        try
          rest_packet := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadString(len);
        except
          on E:Exception do begin Exit; end;
        end;
```

**Client:**

Client is sending data in multithreading to server, about 13 clients is sending data to server thrue one Socket connection. Clients are sending data like this:

```
    EnterCriticalSection(CS);
    // Memo1.Lines.Add(packet); // i can see here that all works fine.
    Ftunnel.Socket.Write(packet);
    LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
```

CS - is global, and created like this:

```
initialization
  InitializeCriticalSection(CS);
finalization
  DeleteCriticalSection(CS);
```

Structure of the packet is:

LengthDATA

example:

0000000015HelloWorldApple

So the bug is in ReadBytes(10) , some times it do not receive the length 0000000015 but receive a mix of data+length, something like: "00015Hello" or "loWorldApp" etc.

Why this is happening, what I'm doing wrong ?

ReadTimeout is default -1

Here how is look Client code:

```
procedure ss_thread.Execute;
var ss : TIdTCPClient;
    unix_time : integer;
    data : TIdBytes;
    packet, s : string;
begin
    // connecting to website to get a data
    ss := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      with TIdTcpClient(ss) do
      begin
        Host := '127.0.0.1';
        Port := 80;
        Connect;
      end;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        ss.Disconnect;
        exit;
      end;
    end;


    // writing a data from server to connected web site server
    try
      ss.Socket.Write(Fff_data);
    except
      on E:Exception do begin end;
    end;


    unix_time := DateTimeToUnix(NOW);


    // getting data from web site server, all looks thread safe?
    while True do
    begin
      ss.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(5);
      if not ss.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      begin
        SetLength(data, 0);
        ss.Socket.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(data);
        s := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(data);
        packet := make_my_length(s) + s;
        ss.Socket.InputBuffer.Clear;
        unix_time := DateTimeToUnix(NOW);
        try
            // sending data from web site, to server
            EnterCriticalSection(CS);
            tunnel.Socket.Write(packet);
            LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
        except
          on E:Exception do begin end;
        end;
      end;

      // disconnecting if no more data for 120sec
      if (DateTimeToUnix(NOW) - unix_time) > 120 then
      begin
        ss.Disconnect;
        break;
      end;

      // killing thread if web site server disconnected us
      if not ss.Connected then
      begin
        break;
      end;

      // disconnecting from web site server and killing thread if tunnel died
      if not tunnel.Connected then
      begin
        ss.Disconnect;
        break;
      end;


    end;

// terminate thread
Terminate;
end;
```

make my length code, works good:

```
function make_my_length(s:string):string;
var len, i : integer;
    res : string;
begin
  if s='' then
  begin
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  res := '';
  len := Length(s);
  if len < 10 then
    for i:=1 to (10 - len) do
    begin
      res := res + '0';
    end;
  Result := res + s;
end;
```

Delphi 2010, Indy 10, Win7

Comment: I added that code, look.

Comment: Why it has to be thread safe if it's run in own thread?

Comment: @waza123: he has multiple threads writing to a single socket connection at the same time.  That is why he has a critical section around the writing.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: `make_my_length()` does not need to be a member of the class.  It does not access any other class members.  It accepts an input String an only operates on that value.  That is thread-safe.

Comment: yep, Marcus Adams suggest didn't work.

Comment: moved the code from CheckForData_from_ss to ss_thread.Execute; but still has a bug. Help please.

Comment: See the edit to my earlier answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptom you have described would be consistent with your client threads NOT sharing a single CS correctly when accessing `Ftunnel`, so that multiple writes could continue overlapping each other, which is what the CS is trying to avoid.  Are you creating the CS in the same unit as your `CheckForData_from_ss()` method?  Did you verify that each thread is indeed accessing the same CS and not different CS's?  Where is `CheckForData_from_ss`() actually be called from? Accessing a `TMemo` (or any other UI control, for that matter) from a worker thread directly, like your code suggests you are, is dangerous and can cause all kinds of side effects if memory is getting corrupted.  You need to synchronize with the main thread, such as with Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class, when accessing the UI.

Another possibility would be if the receiving server is not reading the tunneled data correctly on its end.  For instance, if the server missed some bytes at one point, then all subsequent reads would be at the wrong frame offsets. If you are going to frame your tunneled data, then you should add identifying markers to the frames so you will know if the server is receiving valid frames before you try to decode them, and can recover if the markers get out of sync.

**EDIT:** Try this in your client thread:

```
var
  CS: TCriticalSection;

procedure ss_thread.Execute; 
var
  ss : TIdTCPClient; 
  data : TIdBytes; 
  packet, s : string; 
begin 
  // connecting to website to get a data 
  ss := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil); 
  try
    ss.Host := '127.0.0.1'; 
    ss.Port := 80; 
    ss.ReadTimeout := 120000;
    ss.Connect; 

    // writing a data from server to connected web site server 
    ss.IOHandler.Write(Fff_data); 

    // getting data from web site server
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      SetLength(data, 0); 
      ss.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, -1, False);
      s := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(data); 
      packet := make_my_length(s) + s; 
      // sending data from web site, to server 
      CS.Enter; 
      try
        tunnel.IOHandler.Write(packet); 
      finally
        CS.Leave; 
      end;
    end; 
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end; 

initialization
  CS := TCriticalSection.Create;
finalization
  CS.Free;
```

Comment: * "Are you creating the CS in the same unit as your CheckForData_from_ss() method?" Yes.
* "Did you verify that each thread is indeed accessing the same CS and not different CS's?" Yes.
* "Where is CheckForData_from_ss() actually be called from?" From procedure ss_thread.Execute;
* "if the server missed some bytes at one point, then all subsequent reads would be at the wrong frame offsets." How this can happen?

Comment: Since `CheckForData_from_ss()` is being called in a thread, you have to make sure its code is completely thread-safe to avoid any unwanted side effects. What you showed is not thread-safe as-is. Other than that, I suggest you use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, or attach one of Indy's own `TIdLog...` components to `Ftunnel`, so you can see the actual data that is being transmitted.  That will tell you for sure whether your client app is sending bad data to the tunnel.  If it is not, then the server is not reading the tunnelled data correctly on its end.

Comment: To be more thread safe, I moved all code from CheckForData_from_ss() to ss_thread.Execute; Can you look at it ? I still has a bug.

Comment: Simply moving the code to another area of the same thread does not make it any more thread-safe.  When I say thread-safe, I am talking about shared resources (like the UI) that are accessed across thread boundaries. It is *NOT* safe to access VCL UI components from outside of the main VCL thread. Use `TThread.Synchronize()`, `TIdSync`, or `TIdNotify` to access the UI from a worker thread.

Comment: Why are you sending each packet's length as a string?  Since you control both client and server, sending a binary `Integer` via `TIdIOHandler.Write(Integer)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadInteger()` would be better. You could even stuff your data into a TStream and use the `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` methods, which handle the size integers for you. For that matter, why bother even encoding the data to base64 at all? You could just transfer the original binary data as-is instead.

Comment: Where do you see that I access some UI ?

Comment: Ok, will use this: TIdIOHandler.Write(Integer) and TIdIOHandler.ReadInteger()

Comment: Im using base64 because its easy to see which data is in ReadBytes(10) , because web server is transfering images(binary data).

Comment: In the original code you showed, you were accessing a `TMemo`.  That is in the UI.  In your updated code, you have removed that logic.

Comment: Base64 adds unnecessary overhead.  It bloats the data.  If your sole reason for using it is just to debug the data, then that is not a good use for it since you are wasting bandwidth with it.  Just use Wireshark or another packet sniffer and let it display the raw bytes in a human readible format for you.

Comment: Tested your code, still has a bug. And ReadTimeout and ConnecectTimeout do not work.. tried set it to 1000, nothing, stuck on ReadBytes().

Comment: don't know.. will try to use your ReadStream() Write(TStream) suggestion.

Comment: `ConnectTimeout`, `ReadTimeout`, and `ReadBytes()` work fine when used properly (1s is too small a time for `ConnectTimeout` to work effectively, though. I suggest at least 5s). Please show the updated code you are using now.

Comment: Trying to implement ReadStream and Write(tstream), but having problem with them, because never worked with tstream. Please help. Sending:     packet_stream := TStringStream.Create(packet);
    packet_stream.Position := 0;
    Socket.Write(packet_stream);

Receiving: tunnel.Socket.ReadStream(packet_stream); // but here I stuck, it's freezes forever.

Comment: You are not using `Write(TStream)` correctly, so you are deadlocking your code. Pay attention to the parameters that are available. By default, `Write(TStream)` does not send the stream's `Size`. You need to set its `AWriteByteCount` parameter to True for that. By default, `ReadStream()` does expect that `Size` value, which is why it is freezing.

Comment: So to Send:
packet_stream := TStringStream.Create(packet);
packet_stream.Position := 0;
Socket.Write(packet_stream, SizeOf(packet_stream), True);

Receive:
packet_stream := TStringStream.Create;
tunnel.Socket.ReadStream(packet_stream);
packet := packet_stream.DataString; , Correct ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5854/discussion-between-waza123-and-remy-lebeau-teamb)

Comment: The correct way to send the stream is `Socket.Write(packet_stream, packet_stream.Size, True)` or `Socket.Write(packet_stream, 0, True)`. In the latter case, `0` tells `Write()` to send the entire stream.  A value of `-1` would tell `Write()` to send the stream starting at the current `Position` instead.